# Set reminders to specific day

Tags: microsoft-outlook, reminder

I'm setting up meetings with varying reminders. Some reminders are 2 days and some are same day.

When scheduling a meeting for a Monday 8/13/12 and setting the reminder for 3 days, does send reminders by taking weekends into consideration (sends reminder on 8/10/12) or is it based on what my work week is set to Mon-Fri (sends reminder on 8/8/12)? I don't want it to take weekends into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The reminders are not based on the work week.

Could you just set 5 day reminders for your meetings if they fall on Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday?

If it really needs to be automatically taken care of, you could perhaps write a macro.